# Using LESS string-set property and content method

Tags: css, less

I am setting the string for learning objectives and use the content method to call and display these items. The content method isn't working properly unless I specifically declare a static string. Is this the correct syntax for the content method?

```
&.toc-section .listitem{
    display:none;
    string-set: cnx-learning-objectives content();
}   

&:after {
    display:block;
    background-color: @green;
    content: cnx-learning-objectives content();
    color: red !important;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to set the content of the `listitem` into the `after` element (I think that is what you are trying to do), then I believe this is what you want:

```
&.toc-section .listitem{
    display:none;
    string-set: cnx-learning-objectives content();
}   

&:after {
    display:block;
    background-color: @green;
    content: string(cnx-learning-objectives);
    color: red !important;  
}
```