# What is the modern equivalent to LESS string-set

Tags: css, less

For an example of string-set and what it used to do see [Using LESS string-set property and content method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764700/using-less-string-set-property-and-content-method)

After much confusion I have discovered that this is obsolete and has not been implemented by Chrome since version 39, although it has apparently lived on in LESS.

The textbook use case was to nab the content of the most recent match for a style and put it in a variable so it could then be used by `string(varname)` in a header or footer.

For example, the following would put the content of the `h1` tag into anything with the `.header` class, and the value of `varname` was updated with each successive `h1`

```css
h1 { string-set: chapterTitle; }
.header { content: string(chapterTitle); }
```

What is the modern equivalent?

Comment: _"What is the modern equivalent?"_... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Same as in the cited example. I was _using_ `string-set symbolname content()` and `string(symbolname)` exactly as designed to manage header content when they were so rudely discontinued.

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be an easy equivalent, could you please [edit] your question to describe the problem you're trying to solve? Show what you currently have and explain the result you want. You'll be much more likely to get a solution then.

Comment: paged.js seems to polyfill them but for some reason it's not working for me

Comment: @Rob https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#named-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polyfills are required. Pagedjs can do it, and apparently also LESS.

However, in the code I quote in the question, I was capturing the value incorrectly. It should be as shown below. You can think of `string-set` as a function that takes two values, the symbol name and the source of the symbol value.

Once the value has been captured, the string is available for use and the value can be obtained using `string(SYMBOL_NAME)`. In this case a value is captured every time an H1 element, or an element is encountered with the `chapterTitle` class.

```css
h1 { string-set: chapterTitle content(); }
.header { content: string(chapterTitle); }
```

Similar in application but able to capture entire element graphs is `position: running(ELEMENT_NAME)` which when applied to an element by a class removes the element and all its children from the flow and makes it available for use by `content: element(ELEMENT_NAME);`. The advantage of an element graph rather than a string is you can use things like `<i>`, `<b>`, styled containers or even `<img>` and `<svg>` to tart up the "text" of a running header/footer.

If this is unfamiliar CSS that's because no browser has implemented this part of the standard. But pagedjs will polyfill it for you.